# Array Access Problem in Assembly through data member

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I want to move my index in data member and access it by adding the index to starting address of array(mov dx,[bx + i] ) but i gives its address not its value. What should I do?

```
  ; This method of array access 
    mov ah,2
lea bx,arr ; load address of DW array
mov i,2 ; DW data member
int 21h
mov dx,[bx + i] ; this line is having problem
add dx,30h
int 21h
```

Comment: That's where I'm confused, assembler does not give any severe error and assembles successfully. What happens instead of putting value of 'i' it puts address of i

Comment: Keep your index in a register and you wouldn't have this problem in the first place.  That's what registers are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a variable's value in an index expression. So `mov dx,[bx + i]` is invalid. See *Volume 2, Section 2.1.5* on *page 509* of the current [*Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Development Manual*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) for valid addressing modes of the ModR/M byte (addressing modes) for 16-bit assembly.

> That's where I'm confused, assembler does not give any severe error and assembles successfully. What happens instead of putting value of 'i' it puts address of i

Yes. That is the correct (but unwanted) behaviour. The addressing mode of this instruction is `[BX]+disp16` = `[BX + disp16]` with mode `10111b` (See in the table mentioned in the Instruction Manual). So here disp16 is the address of the variable and not its value. **So the instruction is using the address as an index**. There is no addressing mode for what you want to achieve. You'd have to put the index into a register first, and then use the appropriate addressing mode from the table.

So change the line

```
mov dx, [bx + i]   ; this line is having problem
```

to

```
mov si, i          ; i is a WORD variable
mov dx, [bx+si]    ; correct addressing mode
```

This would generate one correct addressing mode `[BX+SI]` = `00000b` and `010b` for the register `DX`. And according to *Figure 2.2* on page 508, the *ModR/M byte* would be

```
Mod 00......
R/M .....000
Reg ..010...
=== 00010000 = 10h
```